# How to parse > character in Clojure Instaparse?

Tags: clojure, instaparse

I am trying to parse the `>` character in Clojure Instaparse. I have tried `|>` and `|\>` but the parser doesn't seem to recognize any of these. Does anyone know the correct syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would just handle them as strings.  E.g.:

```
((insta/parser 
   "S = '<' tag '>'
   tag = #'\\w+'
   ") "<html>")
; [:S "<" [:tag "html"] ">"]
```

> In instaparse, you can use angle brackets `<>` to hide parsed elements, suppressing them from the tree output.

```
((insta/parser 
   "S = <'<'> tag <'>'>
   tag = #'\\w+'
   ")  "<html>")
; [:S [:tag "html"]]
```